# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

This is a reoccuring problem with this project. I've attempted a couple different solutions and none have worked. Including updating class path version and version number in gradle-wrapper.properties.

Build.Gradle FILE:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha09'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle-Wrapper.properties FILE:

```
#Thu Jan 30 12:09:16 CST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

Comment: Did you update manually the gradle.properties file? Maybe you can try by creating a project from zero in Android Studio

Comment: What's the point in using unstable versions?